# How to make AppBar fixed at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout :

```
    <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
<!--This layout is fixed at the top-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                xmlns:a
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I think this appbar should look fixed at the bottom, but the appbar doesn't look at all. How can I make appbar look at the bottom? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wish to use toolbar as the footer you may,

Things you need to take care of is that you are using `ScrollView` which happens to take all the space on the layout, so to manage that you can use the `layout_weight` attribute, by setting it to `1`, `ScrollView` will take the rest of the space in layout which is left after accommodating the `toolbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_custom_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> OutPut
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are no straightforward ways of doing it. As per Google's design guidelines, App Bar should not appear at the bottom. Read this [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/seamlessness.html).

If you really wanna do this, you can follow this [article](http://android-ed.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-actionbar-at-bottom-of-screen.html). It is for aligning ActionBar at the bottom. But you can use it to align AppBar too.